# Looking for a mini series about the singularity

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, singularity

Looking for the name of a sci fi mini series

Unfortunately I cannot remember the actors/ actresses. The lead actor in the opening scene strolls into a building filled with gunmen quite casually acting cavalier where he is looking for a hostage, he is lead to a room where he is really calm and cool while they cut his head off with a machete. He wakes up in the boot of his car outside the building and gets out then proceeds to grab an m16 and storms the building killing all the gunmen and rescuing the hostage and finding his own body. The rest of the series goes that he works for an agency and he has android bodies and can upload and download to them and the have depots around the world for missions. The series ends up when an ai gaining consciousness and reaching the singularity and in the end the guy goes in to meet the ai and ends up fading away in the ai digital realm

I first saw this on YouTube as a mini series put together as a film/movie. I think. I also think it may have been fan/amateur made but I cannot remember for sure. I could swear domhnall gleeson was in it but I checked his history and I don’t think he was.

Can anyone remember or tell me the name of this show? Almost certain it was made between 2005 and 2015

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: Some producer/director seems to have see *The Matrix* one time too many...

Comment: Welcome to SF&F.  Nice question, but I have a question on it :-).  I am not sure what you mean by "and have depots around the world for missions".  Is this a typo?  Do you perhaps mean "deputies"?

Comment: @Basya A depot is a place for storage. In this context it likely would house weapons, gear, food and other supplies.

Comment: @Basya He probably does mean "depots".  A depot is "a place for the storage of large quantities of equipment, food, or some other commodity", which makes sense in this context of making sure that needed supplies for missions are available in the part of the world the mission is in, not unlike the military having bases, or a business having branch offices.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm - he is talking about uploading to android *bodies*

Comment: @Basya and how does "deputies" make more sense in this context?  I can easily see depots OF ANDROID BODIES so that he doesn't have to always upload to some central lab and then travel halfway around the world again.

Comment: Whatever.  I read it as -- upload to the androids who would be his deputies in different places, and "depots" made no sense to me.  I'd just like it clearer in the question, so we know what the OP meant as we are reading it differently from eachother.

Comment: In roughly which year did you see this? I gather it was no earlier than 2015, but was it in 2015 or more recently than that?

Comment: A deputy is someone else acting with your authority.  A person in an android body is not using a deputy, they are themselves.  The question does not indicate that he can operate multiple android bodies simultaneously, or that the android bodies are capable of independent action., so "deputy" just doesn't make sense, and "depot" does without any sort of mental gymnastics, if you're familiar with the way depots are used.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

The mini series is "[Sync](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2317127/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3)" from Corridor Digital, all episodes published as a single movie can be watched [here](https://youtu.be/vhjimhX9d5U).

> Charlie Cooper is a special agent of the future - the mind of a man running entirely on a computer, able to transfer his consciousness to bio-mechanical bodies at will. But when a computer virus corrupts his system, he must face one of his greatest challenges yet: mortality.

[image: Decapitation about 5 and a half minutes in]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain the specific ways in which it matches the miniseries described in the question. For example, did the main character get his head cut off by gunmen?

Comment: Picture added with hand-drawn circle.

Comment: Thank you for tips, I will do that next time.